# Access, select or utilise names in another worksheet of the same book

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I've created a name database on an Excel sheet and I would like to access, select or utilise any of these names in another sheet of same book.

Comment: So, what do you currently have, where are you stuck? What's the problem?

Comment: Problem is - what program or command do I need to include in the first sheet in  order to be able to call-up those names from the other sheet without having to re-write each name when needed.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood correctly, i think what your referring to is something along these lines -

Say i have 'Hello' in cell A1 of Sheet1 and i want to use this in sheet2 i would write:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Hope i've understood what you are after and this helps! Apologies if this isn't what your after.

Comment: No really but thanks. I was able to get round the problem by using data validation to sellect needed names via a drop list

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) if there is some sort of ID you could reference as a key.

Comment: Thanks for he help. I was able to get round the problem by using data validation to sellect needed names via a drop list –